# How can I preform operations on rows in a Tabular form in MS access?

Tags: ms-access, vbscript

I have a Tabular type Form based upon a `SELECT * FROM table` type of query in MS access.

I would like to:

- check / select rows in this form
- iterate through the checked / selected rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the recordset or the recordsetclone.

```
 With Me.Recordsetclone
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        MsgBox "Field 1 is: " & .Fields(1)
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End with
```

You can also allow the user to highlight records and work with those (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208502).

```
  Function DisplaySelectedCompanyNames()
     Dim i As Long
     Dim frm As Form
     Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

     '' Get the form and its recordset.
     Set frm = Forms![Customers]
     Set rs = frm.RecordsetClone

     '' Move to the first record in the recordset.
     rs.MoveFirst

     '' Move to the first selected record.
     rs.Move frm.SelTop - 1

     '' Enumerate the list of selected records presenting
     '' the CompanyName field in a message box.
     For i = 1 To frm.SelHeight
       MsgBox rs![CompanyName]
       rs.MoveNext
     Next i

  End Function
```